# Scalar with lines to array

Tags: arrays, perl

How can I convert a scalar containing a string with newlines in an array with those lines as elements?

For example, considering this:

```
$lines = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n";
```

I want to retrieve this:

```
$lines[0] --> "line 1\n"
$lines[1] --> "line 2\n"
$lines[2] --> "line 3\n"
```

Ideally, I'd like to keep the newline in the aray elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split`:

```
my @lines = split(/\n/m, $lines);
```

**EDIT**: to keep the newlines, split on `/^/m` as mentioned in the comments, or use a zero-width look-behind, as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Thanks. Just in case: is it possible to keep the newline? And sorry, I should have declared that in the answer more clearly.

Comment: Try splitting on `/^/m` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Davis, works fine. Zero-width match, clever idea.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a negative look-behind to preserve the newline in split:

```
@lines = split /(?<=\n)/, $lines;
```

Comment: sorry, what is the meaning of adding @ before lines?

Comment: @MKSaravanan `@lines` is an array, `$lines` is a scalar.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `split` then `map`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $lines = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n";
my @lines = map { "$_\n" } split /\n/, $lines;
```

Comment: Thanks toolic, looks like a bit advanced to me (Perl beginner) but certainly something to investigate, I never used map.

Comment: @new `map` is quite useful, and not at all as difficult as it seems. I can recommend that you learn to use it.

Comment: @new once I learned the power of `map`/`grep`/`sort` Perl went from a curiosity to the tool I use for all my tasks. Once you understand these look into the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) too!

Answer (score 3):

Another way, without `split`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $lines = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n";
my @lines = $lines =~ /(.*\n)/g;
```